# Monit and /etc/environment

Tags: bash, monit

I have `RAILS_ENV='production'` variable set in `/etc/environment`, and simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
printenv
```

In monit config I check if this script is running.(it's for testing purposes only, as there is no process like this, monit should try to start it with:

`start program = "/home/deploy/www/laptophits/current/bin/importer"`)

I get error in monit logs:

```
[UTC Sep  3 09:31:50] error    : 'importer' failed to start (exit status 0) -- /home/deploy/www/laptophits/current/bin/importer: MONIT_DATE=Sun, 03 Sep 2017 09:31:20
MONIT_HOST=localhost
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
MONIT_PROCESS_PID=-1
MONIT_EVENT=Started
MONIT_PROCESS_MEM
```

So it looks like this bash script runs with just some simple monit variables. How can I make it to run with `/etc/variables` and/or user variables?

Answer (score 1):

To load the /etc/environment variable within monit you have to use `source /etc/environment`

eg;

```
  start program = "/bin/bash -c 'source /etc/environment && cd /srv/<project>/current && /usr/local/rbenv/shims/bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml -e production'" as uid 1000 and gid 1000
```

This will load both the users environment and the /etc/environment file.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your command as:

```
start program = "/bin/bash -c '/home/deploy/www/laptophits/current/bin/importer'" as uid **username** and gid **group**
```

the shell will load the user's environment.